# Add image dynamically in a form inside ion-slide issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using static google map in a form inside ion-slide,
the image appears after the form was created and appeared, so the form damaged, I need to call `update()` but i don't know how and when?

```
 <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red|{{Latitude}},{{Longitude}}&zoom=12&size=300x300&maptype=roadmap"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean _form damaged_? You mean the image url is broken?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I think he means that there isn't enough space to show the entire content of the form, since the slide was created when the image didn't use its _real_ height.

Comment: @Mr_Perfect , when you add any element to an ion-slide you have to update the slide by doing this : 
@ViewChild('slide') slide: any; 
this.slide.update()
so if you don't update the form ion-slide in the end of the slide you see that some input half-disapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's just an image, you can use the `load` event:

```
<img [src]="..." (load)="imageLoaded()">
```

Then in the component code, update the slides to show its content properly:

```
public imageLoaded(): void {
  // Here you can update the slides
}
```